# What is the explanation of the code?

Tags: c, function-pointers

Could anybody tell me what is the following code? Is it function declaration or statement? Is it valid code?

```
static void (*const handle_screens[NO_OF_SCREENS]) (void) =
    { status_screens, settings_screens, access_screens, configuration_screens,
      history_screens };
```

Comment: "Is it valid code?" can be answered by typing it in and compiling it, you know.  As for the rest, it appears to be an array of function pointers, each of which points to a function with no parameters and returning either an opaque data type (`void*`) or nothing (`void`) probably used as some kind of screen handler.

Comment: I believe if they returned Void* it would be

void* (*const handle_screens[NO_OF_SCREENS]) (void)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, EnabrenTane.  I just double-checked the right-then-left rule.

Comment: JMcO: No, that question can't by answered just by typing the code in and compiling it.  Most compilers will erroneously accept some sorts of invalid code.  It's a poor habit to get into assuming that your code is valid just because the compiler accepts it.

Comment: Isn't it obvious he hasn't?  Ever heard of hyper-linking?  [Like this guy?...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481999/what-is-the-explanation-of-the-code/4482048#4482048)

Comment: @JUST - Yeah, I posted that before I read the answers. That's what I get for doing that, I suppose. I kind of feel like we should start closing "what's this crazy C declaration?" questions since a) they inevitably all involve function pointers, and b) `cdecl` almost always gets mentioned, meaning anyone who gets directed to it from a duplicate can use the program (or the website) to answer the question themselves.

Comment: I guess that's easier than cleaning up C's hinky declaration syntax.  :D

Answer (score 9):

its a constant array of function pointers that of signature `void foo(void)`

Those are the easy ones. Google [C Complex Declaration](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=C+Complex+Declaration) for the exciting ones.

Comment: Is it a `void foo(void)` or a `void * foo(void)`?  I've lost track of the nasty function pointer syntax these days.

Comment: said allowed. An Array of pointers to funtions that take void and return void.... I think.

Answer (score 6):

When all else fails, and you're not 100% sure what a declaration is declaring, check out the `cdecl` utility. It's a Linux utility, but somebody's also created a web interface for it at [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org). Pick a random number to insert for the `NO_OF_SCREENS` #define and you get:

```
> static void (*const handle_screens[1]) (void);

declare handle_screens as static array 1 of const pointer to function (void) returning void
```

[Link to result.](http://cdecl.org/?q=static+void+%28%2aconst+handle_screens%5b1%5d%29+%28void%29%3B)

Comment: Nice site.  I'll be using it if saddled with C programming again.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [common rule](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) (which I just refreshed my memory on) covering how to decode C declarations and definitions.  Following the instructions on that link your declaration is:  `handle_screens` is a static array with `NO_OF_SCREENS` entries of `const` pointers to functions without arguments returning `void`.

This array is being initialized with five functions so I'd bet that NO_OF_SCREENS is 5, personally.  This means that [EnabrenTane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481999/what-is-the-explanation-of-the-code/4482008#4482008) is correct in saying that the function definitions are `void foo(void)`.